# Own two colonial nations in the same area

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

As Ireland I have Holland as a vassal. Both of us have colonized Brazil so there is an Irish Brazil and a Dutch Brazil. Will annexing Holland result in having 2 colonial nations in the same colonial area? Or will the two merge?

Comment: Have you progressed far enough into the game to have found the answer to this? I'd say that normally you would get 2 different colonial nations both under Ireland, but I have not had any personal experience of this.

Comment: I am currently diplo-annexing Holland. I will find out in a few years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there was no answer yet, this would indeed result in 2 CNs in the same region.

Comment: Yes, it did. The weird thing is when gaining territory. So far, the territory gained from Portuguese Brazil was given to Dutch Brazil. I do not know if this is based on the proximity to Dutch Brazil (compared to Irish Brazil) or it's just random (select first)